# XAMPP-VM install Redis

Tags: php, web, xampp, localserver, xampp-vm

Moved from Windows to MAC OS, installed and configured a local XAMPP-VM web server, but noticed that it doesn't have (not enabled) Redis. Please tell me how to add Redis to a virtual machine?

Answer (score 0):

If by luck you are using PHP 7.3 this will help you, because it's the current supported version in Debian. Open terminal and run :

```
$ apt install php-dev automake 
$ pecl install redis
```

Otherwise you have to download pecl package, php source code for headers and compile it manually. If you need to have redis in the VM (apt install redis).